# When using ASP.NET WebApi, it doesn't work to put the HttpPost Attribute on an action which names "Delete"

Tags: c#, post, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing, http-delete

I have an action which names "Delete" in an ASP.NET WebApi controller, and I want to request it by HttpPost Method and I don't want to change its name.Even through I put the HttpPost Attribute on it, it also doesn't work and returns "**405 method not allowed**".So what can I do next?

By the way, it is strange that some other actions like this work well.

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ECIS.Mobile.OpenApi.WebApi.Controllers.Manager
{    
    public class AdController : System.Web.Http.ApiController
    {        
        [HttpPost]
        public int Delete(int id)
        {
            return 1;
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: What result do you get when you make a post request? is it a 404?
Could you show us the code of your controller ?
I just did a quick test and was able to call an action named Delete with the HttpPost Attribute

Comment: I get "405 method not allowed",but some other actions like this work well.

Comment: @Joeries is attribute routing enabled or are you using convention based routing? Provide some code as a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've provided some necessary description and sample code.

Comment: Show the route config and also an example of a request that works and the one that fails.

Comment: @Nkosi I just found the reason.The namespace refered shoud be System.Web.Http but not System.Web.Mvc.Much thanks for your remindship.

Comment: Ok so you were using the wrong `HttpPost`. That makes sense.